# Button on top of an imageview and a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have three items in my activity. An image view, button, and linear layout. I want to make the button sit on top of the linear layout and image view.

A sample output is like this:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|       IMAGE VIEW     |
|       ~~~~~~~~       |
|-------|BUTTON|-------|
|       ~~~~~~~~       |
|     linear layout    |
|______________________|
```

I've tried coding it using this XML though, the problem is that the button is not rendering on top of the button and linear layout as what i wanted to happen in the example. Is there a way for this to be implemented?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="package">


<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="3">


    <ImageView

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:src="@drawable/write"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
   />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had hoped your lack of formatting was hiding the markup or code you already had but it looks like you want us to write all of it?

Comment: @rene Thanks for reformatting  my ascii art. I tried writing code to do exactly what i wanted. Tough the problem that i encountered was that the button was set inside the image view only i can't seem to make it go on top of the linear layout too.

Comment: Thanks i've added code that i've tried it seems that the button is in between the image and the linear layout. But then it does not render the button on top of the image and the linear layout. Any suggestions? @rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Co-ordinator Layout in design library by google is made for this type "com.android.support:design:22.2.0"

Comment: Thank You, You pointed me to the right resource. Though with the Floating  action button. Is it possible to replace the small circle with another button?

Comment: Yes it should be possible! Any view can be placed instead of the FAB!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by creatine a relative layout where in the button will be set in the center using **android:layout_centerInParent="true"** then I created a linear layout with **android:weightSum="2"** then i equally divided the linearLayout with an imageView and another linearLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#DDF43F" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom_login"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```